# A triangle mesh algorithm that I am building in processing is not working according to plan

Tags: java, mesh

I am trying to build a randomly generated triangle mesh in processing. I have not completed any CS or math degree yet, so please be gentle in your vernacular or elaborate a bit on what you mean. The triangle mesh is supposed to be made of random PVector points that lead line segments to the two closest points while also closing the triangle. Instead, I get something similar to this:
[The Triangle Mesh.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBmCA.png)

Here is the code:

Triangles.pde:

```
import java.util.*;

int popSize = 10;
ArrayList<Triangle> triangles = new ArrayList();
PVector points[] = new PVector[popSize];

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  background(255);
  try{
  for(int i = 0; i < popSize; i++){
    points[i] = new PVector(random(0, width), random(0, height));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < popSize; i++){
    PVector p1 = points[0], p2 = points[1], p3 = points[2];
    for(int j = 0; j < popSize; j++){
      if(i != j){
          if(dist(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[j].x, points[j].y) < dist(points[i].x, points[i].y, p1.x, p1.y)){
            p3 = p2;
            p2 = p1;
            p1 = points[j];
          }
      }
    }
    triangles.add(new Triangle(p1, p2, p3));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < triangles.size(); i++){

    triangles.get(i).drawTriangle();

  }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    println(e);
  }
}
```

Triangle.pde:

```
public class Triangle{
  public PVector point[] = new PVector[3];
  public PVector center;
  public Triangle(PVector p1, PVector p2, PVector p3){
    point[0] = p1;
    point[1] = p2;
    point[2] = p3;
  }
  public void drawTriangle(){
    noFill();
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    line(point[0].x, point[0].y, point[1].x, point[1].y);
    stroke(0);
    line(point[1].x, point[1].y, point[2].x, point[2].y);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    line(point[2].x, point[2].y, point[0].x, point[0].y);
  }
}
```

What do you think I am doing wrong? And do you have any suggestions that might lead me in the right direction?

Comment: I believe your issue may be that you are not considering if the points are neighbors. I could be wrong though; I am not 100% sure what your algorithm is doing.  Could you and some comments or pseudo code explaining the steps you are taking?

Comment: Generating a triangulation of a point set is not straightforward. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation.